# gtk_container_add crush on mac

Tags: macos, gtk3

I create an GtkFixed object and put it into GtkEventBox via gtk_container_add (with destroying previous child, of course). This way works fine on Windows, but on Mac it crashes.

Stack trace showed me that app crashed on gtk_get_parent. I've tried to user set_parent procedure, but it crashes too:

```
[debug][New Thread 0x1b0f of process 88699]
[debug]Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[debug]0x0000000100b3cf3d in gtk_widget_set_parent () from /usr/local/lib/libgtk-3.0.dylib
[debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
In gtk_widget_set_parent () (/usr/local/lib/libgtk-3.0.dylib)

[debug]> bt 30
[debug]#0  0x0000000100b3cf3d in gtk_widget_set_parent () from /usr/local/lib/libgtk-3.0.dylib
```

Code runned in main thread and in "realize" callback of Window. Same.

The code is:

```
void main_view_reset_list_view(GtkWidget* list_view, GtkWidget* new_item)
{
    GtkEventBox* eb = GTK_EVENT_BOX(list_view);
    GtkBin* bin = GTK_BIN(list_view);
    GtkContainer* container = GTK_CONTAINER(list_view);
    GtkWidget* subview;
    subview = gtk_bin_get_child(bin);
    if (subview)
    {
        gtk_container_remove(container, subview);
        gtk_widget_unparent (subview);
        gtk_widget_destroy(subview);
    }

    gtk_widget_set_parent(new_item, container); // crash
    GtkWidget* parent = gtk_widget_get_parent(container);
    GtkWidget* parent2 = gtk_widget_get_parent(new_item); // 0 on windows, crash on mac
    if (new_item)
    {
        gtk_container_add(container, new_item);
        gtk_widget_show(new_item);
    }

    gtk_widget_show(list_view);
}
```

UPD:
set_parent makes controls dissapeared somehow on windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've traced gtk and glib source code and figured that G_IS_OBJECT() fails, which is quite weird. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12270150/gtkwidget-fails-g-is-object-assertion) have brought me to mind that this issue is pointer-related. I've debugged my code and saw that it is true.

```
GtkWidget* create_widget()
{
   return gtk_fixed_new(); // result points to 0x1018bf830 
}

void refresh_widgets()
{
   GtkWidget* w = create_widget(); // w points to 0x18bf830
}
```

I've actually faced with this kind of issue before, so all code which return pointers has been changed:

```
char* generate_string();
```

to

```
void generate_string(char** out);
```

So in order to fix my problem I have to provide correct pointers in this way. Like:

```
void create_widget(GtkWidget** out);
```

UPD: I've noticed difference between pointers. Shortly say, somehow they are trimmed to 32 bit on 64 bit system on return.

UPD2: Finally, I've made all changes and it works that way.